# combine LocalParams with SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery?

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

does any body know how to combine SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery and LocalParams **(in SOLRnet)**?

I've tried things like thad (don't worry about bad the code, its just to test)

```
         var test = solr.Query(BuildQuery(parameters), new QueryOptions
                        {
                            FilterQueries = getFilterQueries(),
                            Facet = new FacetParameters
                            {
                                Queries = new[] { 
                    new SolrFacetFieldQuery(new LocalParams {{"ex", "dt"}} + "ju_success") , new SolrFacetFieldQuery(new LocalParams {{"ex", "dt"}} + "dr_success") 
                }
                            }
                        });
    ...

         public ICollection<ISolrQuery> getFilterQueries()
                {
//Creating a List of SolrQueries
                    List<ISolrQuery> ISolrQueryList = new List<ISolrQuery>();

//Adding a new SolrQuery to the List. The Solr Query is contains Parameters for multi select
                    ISolrQueryList .Add(new LocalParams { { "tag", "dt" } } + Query.Field("dr_success").Is("simple"));

//Creating the MultipleCriteriaQuery and setting the Operator "OR"
                    var NewMultipleCriteriaQuery = new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(ISolrQueryList , "OR");

//Creating the Resultlist
List<ISolrQuery> Resultlist= new List<ISolrQuery>();
Resultlist.Add(NewMultipleCriteriaQuery);
    return Resultlist();
        }
```

What I try to do are multi-select-facets with a "OR" operator.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: for in-depth Solr questions you probably get a faster (better?) response directly though the mailing list. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/mailing_lists.html

Comment: tips/hints: clean up the code and write a test.

Comment: I've cleaned the code and wrote a test on this, but it doesn't work. Does any ony one know the fail or a solution for my problem?

Comment: @HW90 : please post the test.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the `LocalParams` to the `SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery`.

```
public ISolrQuery GetFilterQueries()
{
    List<ISolrQuery> iSolrQueryList = new List<ISolrQuery>();
    iSolrQueryList.Add(Query.Field("dr_success").Is("simple"));
    iSolrQueryList.Add(Query.Field("dr_success2").Is("simple2"));
    return new LocalParams { { "tag", "dt" } } + new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(iSolrQueryList, "OR");
}
```